# Resize iframe to values smaller than default width/height

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iFrame

```
<iframe src="pageToLoad.html" onLoad="autoResize(this);"></iframe>
```

and a script that resize the iframe according to it's content

```
function autoResize(elem) {
    var newheight;
    var newwidth;

    newheight = elem.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
    newwidth = elem.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
    elem.style.height = newheight + "px";
    elem.style.width = newwidth + "px";
}
```

It's working great!
Except when the iFrame should be smaller than 300px x 150px, than those two values kick in by default.
I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tU5FQ/1/) to display the problem, It seems like 300px x 150px are the default value of an iFrame.
Anyone have an idea how I can fix that, so I can use iFrame with size like 200px x 670px or 980px x 70px ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that I need to set the minimal width and height of the iFrame in CSS first *(200px x 70px)*. than if the values returned by scrollHeight/scrollWidth are lower than the default one *(300px x 150px)* the value returned will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in my experience and is not based on a limit. You likely are not managing the height and width of the content page correctly.

Please include the source for `pageToLoad.html`.

Also: Pro tip for troubleshooting this: HARD CODE the width and height of the iframe first before worrying about javascript.

For example:

```
<iframe src="pageToLoad.html" style="height: 50px; width: 50px;"></iframe>
```

Then you can confirm that your browser lets you go smaller than the default width and height independently of testing your javascript. Once you have confirmed that, fix your javascript.

No way of knowing until you post the inner page, but it is possible that your inner page is growing after the iframe loads it. You can also try messing with height and width for the body of your inner page. For example, this pageToLoad.html works with your auto-resize method:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>iframe test</title></head>
<body style="height: 50px; width: 50px;">
INNER PAGE
<script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```